# Match the conditions to find blank rows & fillup the value in a column

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Table Image]

In the shared table, I want to fillup value if activity is curing & order=NextOrder

I tried using Range.fillup but it's filling only 1 value & also not able to select the criteria of activity & order

Comment: Maybe include your "Range.fillup" code so people can see specifically what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Const KEY_ACT = "Curling"
    ' Load data
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through each row
    For i = UBound(arrData) - 1 To LBound(arrData) + 1 Step -1
        ' Compare Activtiy
        If StrComp(arrData(i, 1), KEY_ACT, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Compare Order
            If StrComp(arrData(i, 2), arrData(i + 1, 2), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' Populate Seq
                If Len(Trim(arrData(i, 3))) = 0 And Len(Trim(arrData(i + 1, 3))) > 0 Then
                    arrData(i, 3) = arrData(i + 1, 3)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update table
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

[image]